# Web Forms for Marketers - Success actions

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

I need other success actions. Is it possible to extend this part of the form? I've already added custom fields and customer save actions. I would like to redirect to a specific URL, not a node in the tree. Is this possible? I see the Success Mode list items under Meta Data but it doesn't look like they are associated with anything (assuming it's hard coded in the framework)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually do this with the existing Success Mode / Redirect. Instead of choosing or entering the path to a Sitecore item, use the Insert External Link option on the Success Page field.

EDIT:
This is done on the form itself. Be sure to use the Insert External Link button to set the value.
[image]

Comment: Where do you see this? Success or Save Actions? Possibly a screen shot? Or on the template directly?

Comment: Thats cool. Unfortunately, this is too complicated for the end user who will be managing these forms. They need to be able to do it from the form editor.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for use in the Page Editor? Maybe look into creating an Edit Frame for the Success Page field, or display it on the page just in Edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this myself but I ended up having to just create a save action to do a redirect. I think it's hardcoded in a way that you can't get to it. If you look at the template for Form, you see there are two fields, one for Success Message and another for Success Page. You can try to change those all you want but it doesn't affect anything.

Update: There is no way to do it that is nice. You would have to bring in tons of code from the sitecore libraries and make changes. The success is hard coded and expects a linkfield to work with even though the template can be a single-line text.

Use the save action or have them edit the template directly like the other answer suggests.